# how to change the table footer color

Tags: vuetify.js

for my model, I'm trying to change the color of the paging buttons at the bottom of the data table, but how is this implemented in vuetify. Is there a way to change the color of the buttons and background color of the footer?

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        :page.sync="page"
        :items-per-page=2
        hide-default-footer
        class="elevation-1"
        @page-count="pageCount = $event"
      ></v-data-table>
      <div class="text-center pt-2">
        <v-pagination
          v-model="page"
          :length="pageCount"
        ></v-pagination>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To change the background of the v-pagination, add a [color class](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/#classes) to it:

```html
<v-pagination
  ...
  class="red"
/>
```

2. To change the color of the active page button, add the [`color`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-pagination/#props) prop to it:

```html
<v-pagination
  ...
  class="red"
  color="green"
/>
```

3. To change the colors of the previous and next buttons, you may manually add style to the `v-pagination__navigation` and `v-pagination__item` classes since there are currently no available props to do it:

```html
<v-pagination
  ...
  class="red"
  color="green my-pagination"
/>
```

```css
.my-pagination {
  /* For previous and next buttons */
  & .v-pagination__navigation {
    background: blue !important;
  }

  /* For page buttons except the active one */
  & .v-pagination__item:not(.v-pagination__item--active) {
    background: yellow !important;
  }
}
```

Here's a sample [demo at codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-feistel-tb5ge?file=/src/components/Playground.vue):

[image]